# Understanding 「…などということは」

Tags: definitions, quotes

From a dictionary definition for なんて ([デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6-590615)):

> なんて の解説
> ［副助］《副助詞「など」に格助詞「と」の付いた「などと」の音変化》名詞、名詞に準じる語、活用語の終止形に付く。
> １ ある事物を例示して、それを軽んじたり、婉曲 (えんきょく) に言ったりする意を表す。なんか。**…などということは。**「手伝いなんてできるか」「本気にするなんてばかね」

**Question (for the bolded portion):** Why is this phrase encapsulated in a いう? Suppose we said for example:

> りんごなど**という**ことは...

and then contrasted it with

> りんごなどは..

What's the difference in nuance between these two things? Is the first one like putting something like dismissive airquotes around "apples":

> As for the so-called "apples and things"... (dismissive tone).

while the second one is just

> As for apples, etc (not as judgmental, and no element of hearsay of what society or other people have forced into the conversation)

?

In general, I feel like という frequently encapsulates things in Japanese, and I never have a good grip as to why (unless it's the easy case, when someone is literally being quoted).

Comment: It's not a sentence just like なんか before it isn't. They are given as alternative ways to say the entry word なんて. And りんごなどことは isn't grammatical.

Comment: If you want to remove という from りんごなどということは, you should remove こと, too.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thanks for the clarification. I edited my question.

Comment: I think usually などということ is preceded by a clause, not a noun like リンゴ. In a sense, ということなどは may be more logical, but much less idiomatic.

Comment: For tangible things like りんご, you use もの, as in りんごなどという**もの**は. こと can probably be used like... eg 「[饑死]{うえじに}などと云う事は、ほとんど、考える事さえ出来ないほど、意識の外に追い出されていた。」(from 『羅生門』)

Answer (score -2):

The **「…などということは」** phrase is encapsulated in a **いう** because it means to emphasize the things or anything before **as noun**, meaning **"... [some subject or noun] which is"**.